# handling ajax return value

Tags: javascript, ajax, return

I searched a lot, but I could not find anything. The function below is making a database request and getting the data through $.post. I get the data in the inner function but I need it outside to equal some data to outputString variable. If you read the code you will see what I need.

```
    function calculatePrice(checkInDate, checkOutDate, nights){

        var rentDetailsArr       = <?php echo json_encode($periods); ?>;
        var minDays = ["<?php echo implode('","',$minDaysArr)?>"];
        var outputString ="";   

            var stDate  = "2010-02-10";
            var endDate = "2010-09-29";

            var xxx = $.post('testData.php', 
                { opType:"getSelectedPeriodDetails", startDate: stDate, endDate: endDate  }, 
                    function getData(data) {

                        $(data).each (function (index){
                            //I am able to get the data in here.but i need to equal it to outputString variable.
                            var price = data['period_id'][0];
                            //alert(price);
                            alert(price);                               
                        });     
                    },  "json");

        //when I equal $.post return to xxx variable, the return is as [object XMLHttpRequest ]
        alert(xxx);

        return outputString;    
    }
```

Now how I can handle the data out side?..can handle the data through xxx variable. If I can , how i will parse it? Sorry, if I have used wrong terms in explaining the problem. I am not very familiar with but I still can use.

Comment: From my experience you can't do it that way (anyone can correct me), you'll need to program whatever is needed to be done differently so that the callback of the AJAX can handle it.

Comment: What is outputString looks like? is it contain price value?

Answer (score 0):

You can set outputString inside ajax callback function like this:

```
$(data).each (function (index){
    // set price to outputString
    outputString = data['period_id'][0];
});
```

Comment: it has been two days that I have asked the question. sorry for late reply. I appreciate with your help. I alert the value of  data['period_id'][0] in the function and I also alert it out of the function using outputString. What I have is out of the function alert is running before inner alert. There is a DB visit inside ajax takes a second or two to alert the response. So there is a sequence problem in there.Thanks very much for all help.Ozlem.

Answer (score 0):

In `$(data).each` the `price` will always have the last index value. I assume you would need all index values. As @alififty answered you could hold it in outputString then make outputString an array that will keep all index values:

```
var outputString = [];

$(data).each (function (index){
    // set price to outputString
    outputString.push(data['period_id'][0]);
});
```

Additionally, if you want to do something with the results like:

```
var price = calculatePrice("xxxx", "xxxx", "xxxx").Tax();
```

Then you could do this by [JavaScript Function Chaining](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-class-instantiation/)

```
function hello() {
  if(!(this instanceof hello))
        return new hello();
  var _hello = "Hello ";
  this.world = function(message) {
    alert(_hello + message);
  }

}
hello().world("World!");
```

Answer (score 0):

Asynchronous JavaScript and XML is **Asynchronous**.

The function you pass to `post` runs *when the HTTP response is received* and not immediately.

You have to handle the data **inside** that callback function. You **cannot** return from it because it is *too late*.